# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework' when running celery -A backend worker -l info

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I'm trying to run my tasks and I'm currently using Celery for this alongside Django and DjangoRestFramework

This is how I've set things up, root directory is also called `backend`

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── save_to_db
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── dump.rdb
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── 0002_auto_20210728_0251.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── serializers.py
    ├── tasks.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

So I have all my configuration for Celery in `celery.py` which I followed from this on how to set up Celery for Django https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html
This is how my config looks like

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')

app = Celery('backend')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

I decided to run this command to get Celery started `celery -A backend worker -l info`

But this gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 133, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 338, in worker
    worker = app.Worker(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 111, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 105, in import_default_modules
    raise response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 276, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 82, in on_import_modules
    self.worker_fixup.validate_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 120, in validate_models
    self.django_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 116, in django_setup
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

I have installed DjangoRestFramework via Poetry and it shows up in my `pyproject.toml` and I've include `rest_framework` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings

Installed apps and some other config for celery in my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'save_to_db'
]

# Celery Configuration Options
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "US/Eastern"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True

# CELERY STUFF
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Comment: So I think the issue is that `rest_framework` seems to work with Python 2 but not Python 3 because when I ran `python3 manage.py runserver 7000` I got a module not found error but when I ran `python manage.py runserver 7000` it was fine

Comment: Could it be that `celery -A backend worker -l info` automatically runs with `python3` instead of `python`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your project running on virtual environment ? If so run celery within virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same issus , for me i installed djangorestframework after building the container thats why i didnt recongnize it after a run the container again.
so what i did is i added the djangorestframework  to my requirments.txt and rebuild the image from scratch